Universal links, while clicking on a facebook post doesn't redirect on my iOS app for all users
We have implemented universal links since a moment on our app (so everything should be setted to make the universal links work with the well known and the metadata for facebook), but it seems that on some device the click on the post always open in the webview of the facebook app and other users, it opens the iOS app with no problem.
Any idea why I have the problem and how to fix it on all devices?

According to facebook doc, we are supposed to use only deeplink url ? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks/add-to-content (Maybe universal link are not handle properly by facebook, so it's why it is randomly working?)
